# How to access cell information and controls of DevExpress Spreadsheet Form from another form in the same application?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress in my own project. I have two forms. the main form is DevExpress Spreadsheet. I want to access spreadsheet form information (cells information) in my second form. The second form isn't spreadsheet and used as a PivoteTable for creating charts. How is it possible?

Comment: Are you talking about a WinForms form?

Comment: I meant Windows Form